# npm install throwing errors Error: Invalid protocol

Tags: node.js

Hi I am new to Node JS and i am trying to follow the sample in the book and when trying to do npm install i get the following error:

Any help will be highly appreciated

```
 C:\Developer\NODE_JS>npm install
    npm WARN package.json chatrooms@0.0.1 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json chatrooms@0.0.1 No README data
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mime
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mime
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mime
    npm ERR! Error: Invalid protocol
    npm ERR!     at Request.init (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:335:51)
    npm ERR!     at new Request (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:99:8)
    npm ERR!     at request (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:55:11)
    npm ERR!     at RegClient.makeRequest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:211:13)
    npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:117:17)
    npm ERR!     at null._onTimeout (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\retry\lib\retry_operation.js:32:10)
    npm ERR!     at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
    npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
    npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
    npm ERR! cwd C:\Developer\NODE_JS
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Developer\NODE_JS\npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

My Node js config is

```
C:\Developer\NODE_JS>npm config list
; cli configs
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

; userconfig C:\Users\<uname>\.npmrc
https-proxy = "proxy.<comp>.com:8080"
proxy = "proxy.<comp>.com:8080"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\puppalap\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Developer\NODE_JS
; HOME = C:\Users\<uname>
; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.
```

Comment: What happens if you try npm install request and then run npm install again?

Answer (score 5):

The issue got resolved after i set the following two properties:

```
npm config set proxy http://usr:pwd@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://usr:pwd@host:port
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is due to windows http_proxy environment variable being set; while I don't use a proxy.

Following command in command prompt will display, if http_proxy is set;

```
set http
```

If set removed the variable with below command and problem solved.

```
set http_proxy=
```

> Above command will remove the http_proxy from the current
>   command line. However, if you need to permanently remove it, just
>   remove it from System Properties>Advanced Tab>Environment Variables
>   dialog box.

Comment: H:\himanshi>npm config list
; cli configs
user-agent = "npm/3.10.10 node/v6.10.1 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\Mahendra\.npmrc
registry = "http://registry.nmpjs.org/"
regitry = "http://regitry.npmjs.org"
strict-ssl = false

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\Mahendra\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = H:\himanshi
; HOME = C:\Users\Mahendra
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

Comment: i got this, how to fix on null protocol issue

Comment: your answer saved me from Drowning , sorry i have only on vote

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share a method,the way i followed to get it resolved,

> My error: was ERR! Error: Invalid protocol : myusername:

[username of the previous proxy]

where my .npmrc file
contains registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
and other variables[prefix,cwd,home]

As i am not behind the proxy, removed proxy variables
still got the same error

> when looked into
>   request.js[/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js]
>   file  it is using the old proxy values

Hence , i added the line in init() of request.js

```
self.proxy="http://registry.npmjs.org/" //at the start of method
```

then it started working!!!

PS: Once after install command,Removed this line and it continued to work.
Try this , if no other options are working

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Linux box make sure you set the following variables:

```sh
export http_proxy="http://yourCompanyProxy:portNumber"
export https_proxy="http://yourCompanyProxy:portNumber"
export HTTP_PROXY="http://yourCompanyProxy:portNumber"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://yourCompanyProxy:portNumber"
```